# compiling expr.y from NetBSD source tree in bison

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm trying to compile simple [expr.y](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/bin/expr/expr.y?rev=1.38&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN) file from NetBSD source tree and when I use bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.2, I'm getting these errors:

```
expr.y:75.14: syntax error, unexpected =
expr.y:82.29: syntax error, unexpected =
```

What's wrong with the file, how it should be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (or have been) some yacc versions out there which accept an `=` before the `{`, e.g.

```
exp:    expr = {
...
    | expr SPEC_OR expr = {
```

just change all that occurences (in that file not more than ten) to:

```
exp:    expr {
...
    | expr SPEC_OR expr {
```